After upgrading to Kubuntu 24.04, Nouveau driver shows black screen when booting with Kernel 6.8.x,
I have an old Nvidia GeForce 210, and use the nouveau driver.
Since upgrading to Kubuntu 24.04, this driver does not co-operate with Kernel 6.8 and shows an entirely black screen shortly after booting. (however, I can ssh to this system from another box, and it is responsive.)
When I boot the same system with the previous kernel 6.5, the display is as it used to be during the past years.
Has the new kernel version dropped its support for old graphics hardware, or is this a bug waiting to be fixed?

I think i habe the same issue

Since my demands on the GPU are low, my solution to this problem was to buy a newer, inexpensive graphics card (GeForce GT 730) that is supported by nvidia-driver-470. I hope this will extend the life of my old ThinkCentre by a couple more years.
